# WCF Data Services Entity Framework Provider fails to recognize inheriting entities

Tags: c#, inheritance, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, wcf-data-services

I'm using Entity Framework (version 6.1.1) code first and the WCF Data Services EntityFramework Provider (still in 1.0.0-beta2 prerelease) to provide the services.

This setup works fine for applications where there are no EF classes that inherit from others.

However, I have an application where I am implementing table per type (TPT) inheritance.  Consider the following code first classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class Organization : Customer
{
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
}
```

These are mapped in a table per type fashion as:

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public  CustomerMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.CustomerID);
        this.Property(t => t.CustomerID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.CustomerName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.ToTable("tblCustomers_Customer");
        this.Property(t => t.CustomerID).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
        this.Property(t => t.CustomerName).HasColumnName("CustomerName");
    }
}

public class OrganizationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Organization>
{
    public  OrganizationMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.CustomerID);
        this.Property(t => t.CustomerID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.OrganizationName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.ToTable("tblCustomers_Organization");
        this.Property(t => t.CustomerID).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
    }
}
```

And the context class:

```
public class ModelContext: DbContext
{
    static ModelContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ModelContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrganizationMap());
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

And the WCF data service using the Entity Framework Provider:

```
public class EFDS : EntityFrameworkDataService<ModelContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Organizations", EntitySetRights.All);
    }
}
```

When the service is initializing, I get the following error, in which the entity set is not found, even though it is defined in the context class:

```
The given name 'Organizations' was not found in the entity sets.
Parameter name: name
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Inheritance does not work directly for DataContract. you have to specify Known Types to work inheritance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx

Comment: Thanks, can you expand on this?  Since I am using the Entity Framework Provider and not setting up DataContracts manually, how would I specify the equivalent of [KnownType(typeof(Organization))] for Customer?

Comment: I guess you can go for partial class. Create a partial class of Customer and than apply Knowtype attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design as per this msdn forum [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/679e1b28-279d-4796-9e0f-54e37c0f49ff/wcf-data-services-entity-framework-provider-fails-to-recognize-inheriting-entities?forum=adodotnetentityframework):

> This is a by designed feature that the refection provider(WCF Data
>   Service provider) is designed to walk all public types/properties, the
>   reflection provider can only expose one entity set for each type
>   hierarchy. It doesn't support so called "MEST" (Multiple Entity Sets
>   per Type), because it would not know which one to pick.

So, my updated WCF service needs to include only the base types, and make sure version 3 of the data service protocol is being used in order to use `OfType<>`, etc. to be able to query and update extending entities:

```
public class EFDS : EntityFrameworkDataService<ModelContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.All);
    }
}
```